# How to pass 2nd argument when 1st argument is defaulted to its value in command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

```
cdcl()          { vlog -source -lint +define+"${1:-DEBUG}" -sv "${2:-*.sv}"; }
```

Above is my fucnction, i defined it in .bashrc file. Below is my command line

```
% cdcl 'RANDOM' 'abc.sv'
```

This give me >> `vlog -source -lint +define+RANDOM -sv abc.sv`

Is there a way, where i can skip giving the 1st placeholder value and only give 2nd placeholder in command line.

Comment: If you mean you only want to pass one argument, you can use options (something like cdc1 --sv 'abc.sv') either coded yourself or using getopts. Otherwise, how would bash know which parameter you meant to pass?

Comment: I want shell to consider default value(DEBUG) of 1st placeholder and it should interpret the argument i enter after cdcl as 2nd argument. How to achieve it?

Comment: Rewrite your alias to take only one argument, the one that is currently $2. Hardcode the current $1 to `DEBUG`.

Comment: aliases don't take arguments, they're a simple substitution of the alias name for the alias definition.  If you need to handle arguments, write a function or a script, not an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function uses the default value expansion with the colon, i.e. `"${1:-DEBUG}"` and not `"${1-DEBUG}"`, an empty value will also trigger the use of the default value. You can pass an empty value with `""` or `''`, so

```
cdcl "" abc.sv
```

should result in the function running

```
vlog -source -lint +define+DEBUG -sv abc.sv
```

If the function had used `"${1-DEBUG}"` instead, it'd only trigger the default value for an unset value, and it's not possible to have `$1` undefined while `$2` is defined. They have to come in order, the list can't have "holes" in it.

Not that passing an empty string like that is a pretty solution, and you might want to decide on e.g. using `getopt` within the function to have it take arguments like `cdcl -d RANDOM -s abc.sv` instead, again with the appropriate default values.

Answer (score 2):

You could check whether your function is called with exactly one parameter and treat that case differently:

```
cdcl() {
  if (($# == 1)); then
    vlog -source -lint +define+DEBUG -sv "$1"
  else
    vlog -source -lint +define+"${1:-DEBUG}" -sv "${2:-*.sv}"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to skip providing the first argument to the script so it uses `RANDOM` but without having to type it. You can revert the order of your arguments.

```
cdcl() {
  local f_pattern="${1:-*.sv}"
  echo "vlog -source -lint +define+${2:-DEBUG} -sv $f_pattern"
  # vlog -source -lint +define+"${2:-DEBUG}" -sv "$f_pattern"
}
```

I used `echo` there to print the command with the arguments it will use. If you are confident, remove the `echo`

Comment: Hello, thanks for ur response. I want shell to consider default value(DEBUG) of 1st placeholder and it should interpret the argument i enter after cdcl as 2nd argument. How to achieve it?